# Is there an os-independent way to atomically overwrite a file?

Tags: file, go, atomic

If the file already exists, I want to overwrite it. If it doesn't exist, I want to create it and write to it. I'd prefer to not have to use a 3rd party library like [lockfile](https://github.com/nightlyone/lockfile) (which seems to handle all types of locking.)

My initial idea was to:

1. Write to a temporary file with a randomly generated large id to avoid conflict.
2. [Rename](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Rename) the temp filename -> new path name.

Comment: If you restrict yourself to POSIX systems, the Rename is the correct way. Windows however doesn't support this on all versions, and not supported by Go on windows.

Comment: @JimB, what do you think about step 1? are there other (significant) steps missing?

Comment: For #1 I'd use [`ioutil.TempFile`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempFile) (with `dir` set to the final directory so that rename won't involve a cross device copy) for creating the temporary rather than trying to generate a random one and handle race conditions yourself.

Comment: but its not about golang.

Comment: For windows, it may be possible to use `ReplaceFile` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365512(v=vs.85).aspx which supports XP to current versions, but you would need to add it alongside shims to the POSIX Rename functions within your own package to make it os-independent. More info at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802690(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`os.Rename`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Rename) calls [`syscall.Rename`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Rename) which for Linux/UNIXs uses the rename syscall (which is atomic*). On Windows [`syscall.Rename`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Rename) calls [`MoveFileW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which assuming the source and destination are on the same device (which can be arranged) and the filesystem is [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) (which is often the case) is atomic*.

I would take care to make sure the source and destination are on the same device so the Linux rename does not fail, and the Windows rename is actually atomic. As Dave C mentions above creating your temporary file (usually using [`ioutil.TempFile`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempFile)) in the same directory as existing file is the way to go; this is how I do my atomic renames.

This works for me in my use case which is:

1. One Go process gets updates and renames files to swap updates in.
2. Another Go process is watching for file updates with [fsnotify](https://github.com/howeyc/fsnotify) and re-[mmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap)s the file when it is updated.

In the above use case simply using [`os.Rename`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Rename) has worked perfectly well for me.

Some further reading:

1. [Is rename() atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054844/is-rename-atomic) "Yes and no. rename() is atomic assuming the OS does not crash...."
2. [Is an atomic file rename (with overwrite) possible on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167414/is-an-atomic-file-rename-with-overwrite-possible-on-windows)

*Note: I do want to point out that when people talk about atomic filesystem *file* operations, from an application perspective, they usually mean the operation happens or does not happen (which [journaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system) can help with) from the users perspective. If you are using atomic in the sense of an atomic memory operation, very few filesystem operations (outside of direct I/O [[O_DIRECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055859/how-are-the-o-sync-and-o-direct-flags-in-open2-different-alike)] one block writes and reads with disk buffering disabled) can be considered truly atomic.