# read() : Invalid arguments

Tags: c, io

I'm trying to read a binary file with `read()` on a well functioning `open()`returned file descriptor but it just doesn't work returning `22` with `errno`.

Here is the code :

```
int input = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY|O_DIRECT);
char buffer_header[4];
if(read(input,buffer_header,4) > 0)
    image_width = bytesToInt(buffer_header);
printf("%d\n",errno);
```

What's happening is that the condition on `read()` is not matched. Am I doing something wrong? The file descriptor returned is `3`.

Comment: `errno` is only valid if there has been an error. You didn't get an error.

Comment: `read()`returns -1 and if I add a `printf()`in the `if`structure it doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only check `errno` if `read` returns `-1` to indicate that it got an error.

```
int n;
if ((n = read(input, buffer_header, 4)) > 0) {
    image_width = bytesToInt(buffer_header);
} else if (n == -1) {
    perror("read");
} else {
    printf("EOF\n");
}
```

Comment: The only possible explanation is that `input` is not a valid descriptor.

Comment: How can I check if it isn't ? Currently `input` is `3`.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you're using the O_DIRECT option.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055859/how-are-the-o-sync-and-o-direct-flags-in-open2-different-alike `O_DIRECT` may have alignment restrictions on the buffer. So maybe `buffer_header` isn't properly aligned. Does it work if you don't use `O_DIRECT`?

Answer (score 4):

I think it may have to do with your if statement being > 0.

Here's what the `read` man page says (type man 2 read in the terminal):

> RETURN VALUE
>          On  success,  the  number  of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number.  It is not an error if
>          this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right now (maybe  because
>          we  were  close to end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or because read() was interrupted by a signal.  **On error, -1 is
>          returned**, and errno is set appropriately.  In this case it is left unspecified whether the file position (if any) changes.

So your code should read something like

```
    if(-1 == read(input,buffer_header,4)) {
        perror("error with read");
    } else {
        do something;
    }
```

Edit: Sorry, just saw the comment thanks Barmar!!
Edit2: Also you should error check the `open` syscall similarly.

```
int input = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY|O_DIRECT);
if(-1 == input) {
    perror("error with open");
} else {
    do stuff;
}
```

[Here's](https://github.com/mikeizbicki/ucr-cs100/blob/2015spring/textbook/assignment-help/syscalls/fd.md) a short tutorial that may help

Comment: Why are you doing something when it returns `-1`?

Comment: whoops! flipped them.

Comment: `open()` seems to work just fine, `error with read` is returned.

Comment: did you try what Barmar said about removing `O_DIRECT`? It seems your syscalls are right though...
another suggestion i can give is to use `BUFSIZ` instead of `4` and `sizeof(buffer_header)`