# Difference between stream and direct I/O in C?

Tags: c, file-io

In C, I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) there are two different types of input/output functions, direct and stream, which result in binary and ASCII files respectively.

What is the difference between stream (ASCII) and direct (Binary) I/O in terms of retrieving (read/write) and printing data?

Comment: streaming is a concept in C++ , you may be confused over it.

Comment: @Steephen: "streaming is a concept in C++ ..." How do you explain [this](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.2)?

Comment: You are confusing _encoding_ with access concept.

Answer (score 4):

No, yes, sort of, maybe…

> In C, … there are two different types of input/output functions, direct and stream, which result in binary and ASCII files respectively.

In Standard C, there are only file streams, `FILE *`.  In POSIX C, there are what might be termed 'direct' file access functions, mainly using file descriptors instead of file streams.  AFAIK, Windows also provides alternative I/O functions, mainly using handles instead of file streams.  So "No" — Standard C has one type of I/O function; but POSIX (and Windows) provide alternatives.

In Standard C, you can create a binary files and text files using:

```
FILE *bfp = fopen("binary-file.bin", "wb");
FILE *tfp = fopen("regular-file.txt", "w");
```

On Windows (and maybe other systems for Windows compatibility), you can be explicit about opening a text file:

```
FILE *tcp = fopen("regular-file.txt", "wt");
```

So the standard distinguishes between text and binary files, but file streams can be used to access either type of file.  Further, on Unix systems, there is no difference between a text file and a binary file; they will be treated the same.  On Windows, a text file will have its CRLF (carriage return, line feed) line endings mapped to newline on input, and newlines mapped to CRLF line endings on output.  That translation does not occur with binary files.

Note that there is also a concept ['direct I/O'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055859/how-are-the-o-sync-and-o-direct-flags-in-open2-different-alike) on Linux, activated using the `O_DIRECT` flag, which is probably not what you're thinking of.  It is a refinement of file descriptor I/O.

> What is the difference between stream (ASCII) and direct (Binary) I/O in terms of retrieving (read/write) and printing data?

There are multiple issues.

- First, the dichotomy between text files and binary files is separate from the dichotomy between stream I/O and direct I/O.
- With stream I/O, the mapping of line endings from native (e.g. CRLF) to newline when processing text files compared with no such mapping when processing binary files.
- With text I/O, it is assumed that there will be no null bytes, `'\0'` in the data.  Such bytes in the middle of a line mess up text processing code that expects to read up to a null.  With binary I/O, all 256 byte values are expected; code that breaks because of a null byte is broken.
- Complicating this is the distinction between different code sets for encoding text files.  If you have a single-byte code set, such as ISO 8859-15, then null bytes don't generally appear.  If you have a multi-byte code set such as UTF-8, again, null bytes don't generally appear.  However, if you have a wide character code set such as UTF-16 (whether big-endian or little-endian), then you will often get zero bytes in the body of the file — it is not intended to be read or written as a byte stream but rather as a stream of 16-bit units.
- The major difference between stream I/O and direct I/O is that the stream library buffers data for both input and output, unless you override it with `setvbuf()`.  That is, if you repeatedly read a single character in the user code (`getchar()` for example), the stream library first reads a chunk of data from the file and then doles out one character at a time from the chunk, only going back to the file for more data when the previous chunk has been delivered completely.  By contrast, direct I/O reading a single byte at a time will make a system call for each byte.  Granted, the kernel will buffer the I/O (it does that for the stream I/O too — so there are multiple layers of buffering here, which is part of what `O_DIRECT` I/O attempts to avoid whenever possible), but the overhead of a system call per byte is rather substantial.

Generally, you have more fine-grained control over access with file descriptors; there are operations you can do with file descriptors that are simply not feasible with streams because the stream interface functions simply don't cover the possibility.  For example, setting `FD_CLOEXEC` or `O_CLOEXEC` on a file descriptor means that the file descriptor will be closed automatically by the system when the program executes another one — the stream library simply doesn't cover the concept, let alone provide control over it.  The cost of gaining the fine-grained control is that you have to write more code — or, at least, different code that does what is handled for you by the stream library functions.

Answer (score 2):

Streams are a portable way of reading and writing data. They provide a flexible and efficient means of I/O. A Stream is a file or a physical device (like   monitor) which is manipulated with a pointer to the stream. 
This  is `BUFFERED`  that is to say a fixed `chunk` is read from or written to a file via some temporary storage area (the buffer). But data written to a buffer does not appear in a file (or device) until the buffer is flushed or written out. (`\n` does this).

In Direct or low-level I/O-

This form of I/O is UNBUFFERED -- each read/write request results in accessing disk (or device) directly to fetch/put a specific number of  bytes. 
There are no formatting facilities -- we are dealing with bytes of information. 
This means we are now using binary (and not text) files.