# Do read and write C system calls use buffers?

Tags: c, io, system-calls, read-write

I was talking with a teacher and he told me that read and write system calls was using buffers, because there is a variable in your system spec that controls how many times you can have access to the device you want to read/write on, and the system uses buffer to stock data while he is waiting for writing on the device.

I saw on an other Stack Overflow post ([C fopen vs open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658476/c-fopen-vs-open)) that one of the advantages of `fopen` and `fwrite` functions was that those functions were using buffers (which is supposed to be way faster). 
I have read the man page of `read` and `write` sys calls, and the man pages do not talk about any buffers.

Did I misunderstood something ? How do `read` / `write` C syscall buffers work?

Comment: There might be quite a few misunderstandings here, and it's hard to say where they all originated. First and foremost, C is a portable language. There are C compilers for multiple Operating Systems, and they all work differently behind the scenes. So you can't make assumptions on how the (operating) system works. That said, `read` and `write`  are NOT C functions. they're OS functions.

Comment: There is no such thing as C system call. There are OS system calls, and there are C functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functions you mention, `read` and `write` are system calls, therefore their behavior is platform dependent.

As you know, `fread` and `fwrite` are C standard library functions. They do buffering in the user space and in this way optimize the performance for typical application. `read` and `write` are different. There is some stub code in userspace C libraries (such as GNU libc) for these functions, but the main function of that code is just to provide a convenient wrapper for invoking the right kernel functionality (but it's also possible to invoke that functionality with `syscall()` directly!)

If you're interested in the details, [here](https://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/sysdeps/linux/common/write.c) is an example: the wrapper for `write` system call in the uclibc library.

So the typical implementations of `read` and `write` do not do buffering in user space. They may still do buffering in the *kernel space*, though. Read about the `O_DIRECT` flag for more details: [How are the O_SYNC and O_DIRECT flags in open(2) different/alike?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055859/how-are-the-o-sync-and-o-direct-flags-in-open2-different-alike)

Comment: Thanks ! Do you know where can I read the exact behavior of the read/write syscall of my system?