# How to measure execution time of file I/Os in C programs on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, time, disk, measure

I want to measure execution time of file I/Os in C programs on Linux. 
I found a lot of questions and answers regarding measuring times.

But, I think any of the answers would not work for my purpose.

Functions related with real-time clocks are not proper in my case
because I want to exclude time consumed by other processes.
(e.g. `gettimeofday`, `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW)`)

Functions related with CPU time are not proper in my case, either,
because I want to include wait time for disk I/O.
(e.g. `getrusage`, `clock`, `clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID)`)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `open`, `read`, and `write` calls for direct measurement of disk I/O speed, avoiding automatic stream buffering (like `fopen`).

For `read` and `write` you should verify bytes read and written.

To time just use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID,*tp)` or `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523442/difference-between-clock-realtime-and-clock-monotonic)). I say that because Linux [includes kernel/system time](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) on behalf of the process (this is explicit on the man entry for `clock_gettime` only [on OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/clock_getres)). You may want to make sure you are filling the disk cache, and potentially the kernel disk page cache, if you want to measure continuous (non-burst) speed. This way your call to `open` will return only after completing file write.

Only using the above process will give you the results you would get in normal usage using kernel disk page caching. You can further bypass kernel page caching as follows. But keep in mind that these are "raw" results and will not necessarily correspond to results when you are using kernel page caching, as Basile Starynkevitch described.

Call [`open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) with `O_SYNC|O_DIRECT` operating mode flags (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055859/how-are-the-o-sync-and-o-direct-flags-in-open2-different-alike/16259319)). `O_DIRECT` bypasses kernel page caching. This way your data will be confirmed to be completely transferred to and from disk rather than computer RAM cache.

> ```
>    O_DIRECT (since Linux 2.4.10)
>           Try to minimize cache effects of the I/O to and from this
>           file.  In general this will degrade performance, but it is
>           useful in special situations, such as when applications do
>           their own caching.  File I/O is done directly to/from user-
>           space buffers.  The O_DIRECT flag on its own makes an effort
>           to transfer data synchronously, but does not give the
>           guarantees of the O_SYNC flag that data and necessary metadata
>           are transferred.  To guarantee synchronous I/O, O_SYNC must be
>           used in addition to O_DIRECT.  See NOTES below for further
>           discussion.
> ```

Unless I am mistaken you will not have to worry about the kernel scheduling another process onto your CPU in testing unless most of your CPUs are busy. Even if it does schedule another process it may return to your process as soon as the synchronous write has completed (please let me know as a comment if you know). Therefore using `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` instead may not matter. `cpuset` might be useful.

Consult Linux `man` entries and The GNU C Library Reference Manual. Also see `fsync` and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464184/are-file-edits-in-linux-directly-saved-into-disk) about how long page-cached writes take to hit disk.

Answer (score 0):

Read both [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and about the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), then a textbook about [operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

> I want to measure execution time of file I/Os in C programs on Linux

Your question does not make real sense. Disk I/O or [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) is a whole computer activity, not just done by a particular [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) doing some [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). For example, 
 [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) some big file (of several dozens of megabytes) on your system and run `time wc` several times on it. See [wc(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html) and [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html).

In particular the kernel would handle [page faults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault) (with help from the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) inside your processor), and a given page can be [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)-ed many times by different processes.

Drepper's paper [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) and the [dynamic linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) (see [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) ...) are relevant.

In practice, in 2020, most [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executables are dynamically linked (e.g. to `libc.so`). See [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) and [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) and [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

See also [kernelnewbies.org](https://kernelnewbies.org/), [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/), https://www.linuxatemyram.com/