# Linux character device driver and cache coherent

Tags: linux, caching, memory, file-io, linux-device-driver

my device is xylinx zynq ultrascale zcu106 evk.
and i reserve 4GB of DDR memory for specific usage.
this area is **platform device** and also controlled by **character device driver**.

if i want write data to physical storage immediately, open file with flag "O_SYNC".
`fd = open("myfile",O_RDWR|O_SYNC);`

also i can use these file i/o interface for control character device driver.
shell : `mknod /dev/my_chrdev c 99 0`
c program : `fd = open("/dev/my_chrdev",O_RDWR|O_SYNC);`

- I want to know what effect it has when opening a character device node with the "O_SYNC" flag.
- And how can I guarantee the cache coherent of i/o for the character device?.
- Does the file io interface give feedback when a device node is opened through the sync flag in the user level application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are the O\_SYNC and O\_DIRECT flags in open(2) different/alike?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055859/how-are-the-o-sync-and-o-direct-flags-in-open2-different-alike)

Comment: There is no default handling of `O_SYNC` for character special device files (it is usually ignored), but you could add code to handle it in your driver's "write" or "write_iter" file operation handlers.